# How to pull all subelements from subarray?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My document is like this:

```
// collection: photos
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5835840fb6ca90e020020b22"),
    "customerIds" : [
        {
            "code" : "SHDR327D7DVKHBT3",
            "cType" : "photoPass",
            "userIds" : ['aaa','bbb']
        },
        {
            "code" : "SHDR327D7DVKHBT3",
            "cType" : "photoPass",
            "userIds" : ['ddd','aaa','ccc']
        }
    ]
}
```

The two documents in `customerIds` are the same. Now I want delete all 'aaa' out of `userIds`, how can I achieve that in one command?

I use this command to delete them, but only one can be deleted at a time.

```
db.photos.update(
         {"customerIds.code":'SHDR327D7DVKHBT3',"customerIds.userIds":'aaa'}, 
         {$pull: {"customerIds.$.userIds":{$in:['aaa']}}},
         { multi: true,upsert: false}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you wanted to do ?

```
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$customerIds"},
    {$unwind:"$customerIds.userIds"},
    {$match:{"customerIds.userIds":"aaa"}},
    {$project:{"customerIds.userIds":1,_id:0}}
])
```

this will return you the 'aaa':

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584708e6888ff31225c2e375"),
        "customerIds" : {
                "userIds" : "aaa"
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("584708e6888ff31225c2e375"),
        "customerIds" : {
                "userIds" : "aaa"
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but in fact I want to know is how to delete them...